# JS else/else if

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

```
var movies =
[ 
  {
    title: "Shawshank",
    rating: 5,
    hasWatched: true
  },
  {
    title: "Boardwalk empire",
    rating: 5,
    hasWatched: true
  },
  {
    title: "bladerunner",
    rating: "unkown",
    hasWatched: false
  },
  {
    title: "Ratatouille",
    rating: 4,
    hasWatched: true
  }
]

for(var i = 0; i <movies.length; i++)
{
if(movies[i].hasWatched)
  {
      console.log("You have seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + 
  movies[i].rating);
  }
else (movies[i].hasWatched !== true)
  {
      console.log("You have not seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + 
  movies[i].rating);
  }
}
```

When i change the else-if to else it produces this output:

- You have seen Shawshank - 5
- You have not seen Shawshank - 5
- You have seen Boardwalk empire - 5
- You have not seen Boardwalk empire - 5
- You have not seen bladerunner - unkown
- You have seen Ratatouille - 4
- You have not seen Ratatouille - 4

Why does the code seem to fall through in this case?

I am particularly interested in why bladerunner is only output one. The only apparent difference is that the rating property is "string" and not "number".

Best

Comment: It's `else if` not `else`

Comment: remove `(movies[i].haswatched !== true)`

Comment: `else` shouldn't even work with statement

Comment: Else should not have a condition

Comment: Is this cause by giving Else a condition?

Comment: It's bugging out because nothing comes after else. You can use `else if` that way, but not `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` statement doesn't use a conditional expression.
The expression followed by the `else` statement is executed unconditionally.

In this example:

> ```
> else (movies[i].haswatched !== true)
>   {
>       console.log("You have not seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + 
>   movies[i].rating);
>   }
> }
> ```

The `else` statement will execute the expression `(movies[i].haswatched !== true)`, which has no effect whatsoever. It's like a statement `foo === true;`. It's interpreted, executed, and it has no effect whatsoever on the program.

The posted code is equivalent to this, the semicolons I added to clarify the end of statements:

```
for(var i = 0; i <movies.length; i++)
{
  if(movies[i].hasWatched)
  {
      console.log("You have seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + 
  movies[i].rating);
  }
  else (movies[i].hasWatched !== true);

  console.log("You have not seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + movies[i].rating);
}
```

That is, the last `console.log` statement is *always* executed.

You probably meant to write like this:

```
if (movies[i].hasWatched) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need either an `if` for checking another condition

```
} else if (movies[i].haswatched !== true)
//     ^^
```

or omit the condition, because you checked already the condition with a true condition, then you need just for the `else` part no new check with reverse condition.

```
} else {
    //...
}
```

```js
var movies = [{ title: "Shawshank", rating: 5, hasWatched: true }, { title: "Boardwalk empire", rating: 5, hasWatched: true }, { title: "bladerunner", rating: "unkown", hasWatched: false }, { title: "Ratatouille", rating: 4, hasWatched: true }],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
    if (movies[i].hasWatched) {
        console.log("You have seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + movies[i].rating);
    } else {
        console.log("You have not seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + movies[i].rating);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an open and shut case.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i <movies.length; i++)
{
  if(movies[i].hasWatched)
  {
       console.log("You have seen " + movies[i].title + " - " +   movies[i].rating);
  }
  else
  {
        console.log("You have not seen " + movies[i].title + " - " + 
                     movies[i].rating);
  }
}
```

use only else instead of giving another condition. it will solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You've been tricked by JavaScript tendency to play along with whatever you through at it...

When you have an `if .. else` statement, the statement following the `else` keyword is executed when the `if` condition is falsy. In your case, that statement is simply a comparison within parentheses, just as you would write:

```
var something = 1;
(something === 1);
```

Perfectly legal, not very useful.

After that, you have another valid piece of code, a simple block, like this:

```
var something = 1;
{
   alert(something);
}
```

Again, perfectly legal, but in its on, not useful.

---

So how does this cause the output you saw?

Well, the code block after the `if .. else` is executed **for every item**. You always see "You have not seen...". The `if` part also prints those items with `hasWatched === true`.

Ohh, and that Bladerunner row? that's just the value of `rating` for that object...

Answer (score 0):

When you give `else` a condition it thinks it's the code that should be executed when the `if` isn't true. And as a result the code below is seen as just another block to be run every time.

Try running this:

```js
if (false) {
  console.log("hello")
} else(console.log("whoops")) // this turns into the else block to be run when if is false.
{
  console.log("goodbye") // this runs every time.
}
```

This is a result of the fact that you can (but probably shouldn't) write `if/else` like this:

```
if (false)
    console.log("if")
else console.log("else")
```

Adding parenthesis doesn't change the else block. This is identical:

```
if (false)
    console.log("if")
else (console.log("else"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is (as mentioned by several other answers): `else` statement does not accept/evaluate a predicate.

## Explanation:

[if-else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#If.E2.80.93then.E2.80.93else_expressions) is an *expression* for creating two *branches* in the program flow, and letting the flow to be chosen by the result of evaluating the *[predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic)* of the `if` statement.

After the predicate is evaluated to a *[Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) Condition*, then depending on whether the result is a `true` or `false`, the *if-block* or * else-block* of the expression will be executed, respectively.

### Simple Program Without if-else

Let's say the flowing program executes two statements: *(begin)* and *(end)*

```
// (beging)
// (end)
```

The flow of this program would look like:

```
   (begin)
      |
      |
    (end)
```

### Simple Program with if-else

We inject an `if-else` expression in the middle of the previous program as follow:

```
// (begin)
if( predicate ) {
    // (A) if-block
}
else {
    // (B) else-block (or alternative-block)
}
// (end)
```

Which is **equivalent*** to:

```
// (begin)
if( predicate ) {
    // (A) if-block
}
else if ( !predicate ){
    // (B) else-block (or alternative-block)
}
// (end)
```

And the flow now is changed to:

```
   (begin)
      |
      |
     / \
    /   \
  (A)   (B)
    \   /
     \ /
      |
      |
    (end)
```

### Simple Program with if else-if

We can chain `if-else` expressions and create `if else-if else` expressions. To do so we need to have an `if` statement, followed by any number of `else if` (or in some languages `elif`) statements, and finally, followed by an `else` statement:

```
// (begin)
if( predicate_1 ) {
    // (A) if-block
}
else if ( predicate_2 ){
    // (B) else-if-block (or alternative-block)
}
// more else-if statements can be added here
else {
    // (C) else-block (or otherwise-block)
}
// (end)
```

So if we look at the flow, adding `else-if` statements, increases the ways we can get from *(begin)* to *(end)*

```
   (begin)
      |
      |
     /|\
    / | \
   /  |  \
  /   |   \
(A)  (B)  (C)
  \   |   /
   \  |  /
    \ | /
     \|/
      |
      |
    (end)
```

*NOTE: In some languages like [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) you are required to have complete conditional expressions (i.e. an `else` statement if required to close the gap in the conditional expression). So for example, in Haskell, the following will not compile:

```
if predicate_1
then  -- if block
else if predicate_2
then -- else-if block
```

that is because at the end there needs to be an `else` statement to close the gap, so the following fixes the error:

```
if predicate_1
then  -- if block
else if predicate_2
then -- else-if block
else -- else block
```